# How to make pass by reference method working

Tags: c#

I wrote a reference method in a class, and call it in `public partial class DYBook : Form`, but it is not working, the value doesn't change. If I put postCode.Text instead of temp, there will return an error. I don't know what was wrong here.

```
public static bool DYPostalCodeValidation(ref string inputField)
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^([A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z][\s]?\d[A-Za-z]\d)$");
    if (inputField == "" || inputField == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (pattern.IsMatch(inputField))
    {
        inputField = inputField.ToUpper();
        if (inputField.Length == 6)
        {
            inputField = inputField.Insert(3, " ");
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

call it here

```
Private string temp;
temp = postalCode.Text;

if (DYValidation.DYPostalCodeValidation(ref temp) == true)
{
    postalCode.Text = temp;
}
else
{
    postalCode.Focus();
    errorMessage.Text += "Postal Code is invalid" + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't pass directly `postalCode.Text` as a reference parameter. Instead, your pathway is correct.

To solve the problem, put a breakpoint where you check `pattern.IsMatch(inputField)`. Make sure your input match with the regex. If these lines of codes doesn't run, you can't obtain what you want to.

```
else if (pattern.IsMatch(inputField))
{
    inputField = inputField.ToUpper();
    if (inputField.Length == 6)
    {
        inputField = inputField.Insert(3, " ");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

postalCode.Text is a property which internally will be interpreted as method-call.
The ref keyword expects a reference to a variable and NOT to a method.

Answer (score -2):

`=` will reassign a reference

You need to modify the string reference itself, not reassign it.

For example, an actual input field object would allow for

```
inputField.Text = inputField.Text.ToUpper();
```

This will preserve the input field reference, but update its inner Text property

Comment: That's why the parameter is a `ref` parameter. It's absolutely fine to change the parameter's value to a different reference.

Comment: It appears the OP is expecting it to update their original TextBox's Text Property. ref isn't going to be much help in that case